# how to switch from outgoing port 25 to 587 in postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I would like to send a mail to a gmail address:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" user@gmail.com
```

That is what I see in the logs

```
connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.27.27]:25: Connection refused
connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4025:401::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4025:c03::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.9.27]:25: Connection refused
connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.27]:25: Connection refused
Apr  9 20:04:02 ubuntu postfix/smtp[157056]: 228717CAA0: to=<user@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.22, delays=0.09/0.09/0.04/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.27]:25: Connection refused)
```

tried to test this destination with netcat and the result was the same:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nc -zvn 142.251.9.27 25
nc: connect to 142.251.9.27 port 25 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

then I checked the port 587 with the following command - which went ok:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = smtp.gmail.com
verify return:1
```

so I tried to force postfix to use encryption according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/120123/forcing-encryption-for-outgoing-smtp-with-postfix) so modified the main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

but still trying to use port 25 which is blocked. So my question is that how can I force postfix to use different port from 25 to be able to send outgoing mails?

Answer (score 5):

> but still trying to use port 25 which is blocked. So my question is that how can I force postfix to use different port from 25 to be able to send outgoing mails?

You *can't*.

Or well, you can force Postfix to do that. But the rest of the world expects e-mail to come via port 25. Using port 587 won't work - that's for authenticated submissions (hint: the port is *named* that) from client software. Not for SMTP server to SMTP server communication.

You *have* to tell your ISP to open port 25. Any business ISP should cater to such a request.

Comment: so I would like to send a mail towards gmail not using remote port 25 - I think smtp gmail listens on other ports as well, like 587 - so should I send mail with submissions then? thx

Comment: No! Talk with your ISP and tell them to open port 25. Noone expects incoming e-mail on port 587, that is for ***CLIENT***, e.g. end user, submission of mail. Again: Read the *first* sentence of my answer.